# Java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/upload__67974291_17b824653b6__7ffb_00000014.tmp (No such file or directory) (Struts2)

Tags: java, struts

Estoy trabajado en una app web, migrandola de framework Struts1 a Struts2, y ahora estoy presentando el sigueinte conflicto.

Una de la funcionalidades requiere de subir archivo TXT para que sea leido, compara que los registros esten el DB y si estan hace la actualizacion de un campo en especifico.

Esta app esta en un servidor OpenSuse y uso Websphere para el deploy.

El problema es que en mi local la aplicacion hace las actualizaciones en la DB y no me causa ningun conflicto, igual he pedido que otras personas hagan pruebas y funciona bien, uso Tomcat o GlassFish para correrla.

Cuando hago el deploy de la aplicacion en el server usando Websphere, obtengo el error:
**"Java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvr/temp/AppSrvrNode01/server1/upload__67974291_17b824653b6__7ffb_00000014.tmp (No such file or directory) (Struts2) "**

No me queda claro el porque pasa eso en el servidor, abajo una parte del log de websphere.

```
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvr/temp/AppSrvrNode01/server1/upload_1ac86a68_932c_4e40_a7b7_ae4ab040b8c5_00000045.tmp (No such file or directory)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:83)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at com.actions.MassUpdateListPageAction.processAction(MassUpdateListPageAction.java:431)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
[8/20/21 15:45:14:336 EDT] 000000b2 SystemErr     R     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
```

Abajo la parte de codigo donde mostro conflicto con el
**Codigo con Struts 1(version anterior)**

```
FormFile formFile = null;
formFile = massUpdateForm.getOwnDivfile();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(formFile.getInputStream()));
```

**Codigo con Struts2**

```
File formFile = null;
formFile = massUpdateForm.getCompIDfile();
System.out.println("file ---"+formFile );
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(formFile));
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
```

Quedo a espera de sus sugerencias,

Comment: Creo que hay una confusión en las rutas, el error dice que se intenta leer un archivo que no existe en determinada ruta, primero dijiste que al hacer deploy daba error al leer el archivo desde la siguiente ruta: ``/opt/WebSphere/AppServer/elarchivo.tmp``, Pero luego el LOG dice que el error fue al intentar leer esta otra ruta: ``/opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvr/temp/AppSrvrNode01/server1/PIFWeb3_war/PIFWeb.war/elarchivo.tmp`` Podrías verificas si existe el archivo: ``upload_1ac86a68_932c_4e40_a7b7_ae4ab040b8c5_00000045.tmp`` en la ruta que muestra el LOG?

Comment: la ruta es la misma, olvide agregar el path completo, gracias por la observacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era que en el servidor la carpeta de WebSphere borraba los archivos (no tenía accesos al server y hasta que los pedí pude ver el comportamiento de los archivos) y cuando mi método intentaba buscar el archivo, ya no estaba. Mi solución fue crear una carpeta en el server para almacenar el archivo y crear un método que eliminara el archivo una vez que fuera leído.